# How to get ORDERED and limited rows form MySQL and randomize show order

Tags: php, mysql

Is possible, and how to ask MySQL for

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER by row_id DESC LIMIT 8
```

get the last 8, newest record from my table, with randomized order for PHP showing method

```
$results = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['my_col_name'];
}
```

Colud I, and where put the `rand()` in my SQL query?
Without randomize I get last 8 rows ORDERED 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3

I want to get in the following order:

9,7,5,4,6,10,3,8;

8,7,3,6,10,9,5,4
...

Comment: Remember, `ORDER BY RAND()` on large tables can be cripplingly slow.

Comment: What is a large table - over 1k,1M or 1G rows or all table size (MB,GB) ?

Comment: It's a factor of overall size, so rows or data or both. Try creating a dummy table with a huge number of rows to test how it performs on your hardware.

Comment: On the other hand I randomise only few rows (8), not all the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place it inside another select:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER by row_id DESC LIMIT 8) t ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM my_table t
      ORDER by row_id DESC
      LIMIT 8
     ) t
ORDER BY rand();
```